# Tab Completion Broken on SCP with OpenSSH 1:6.2p2-6ubuntu0.1

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, file-transfer, scp, ubuntu-13.10

Here is my scenario:

I want to transfer `~/foo.txt` to a server `aoneill@bar`.

I start typing in my command line:

```
aoneill@aoneill-Laptop:~$ scp fo
```

At this point I hit `<tab>` to complete the file name, and my terminal just freezes up. It won't change based on any keystroke, and the cursor is just stuck right next to the `fo`, unless I `<ctrl-C>` out.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10, and I do include `. /etc/bash_completion` in my `.bashrc`.

This is the only program I really encounter this issue with, and it doesnt seem to be a common problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think we need more info to figure this out.  Does this happen with every file and every folder?  It only happens with `scp`? Do you have any customizations in `~/.bashrc`?  What configuration do you have to look up hostnames, is it DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At this point I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete the file name, …

… and the computer, *entirely failing to read your mind*, did what it *actually* does when <kbd>tab</kbd> is hit at that point, which is try to complete a *hostname*, possibly consulting all sorts of things from the output of `avahi-browse` to the output of `ruptime`.  This process can take some time.

(The brave can go and look at the `_known_hosts_real` function in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash-completion`.)

To have completion of a *filename* at that point, the word that you have typed **must** either contain a slash (`/`) character or begin with a dot (`.`) or a tilde (`~`) character.

(The brave can similarly see why that is from the `_scp` function in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/scp`.)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I'll keep that in mind when I use ssh/scp in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with Ubuntu 14.04.  Using set -x shows that the autocomplete was hanging on ruptime.  When I tried to run ruptime myself I found that it wasn't installed.  After installing the rwho package the hang was fixed.

sudo apt-get install rwho

```
COMPREPLY+=($( compgen -W         "$( ruptime 2>/dev/null | awk '!/^ruptime:/ { print $1 }' )"         -- "$cur" ))
+++ ruptime
+++ awk '!/^ruptime:/ { print $1 }'
```

The COMPREPLY line calls ruptime without checked to see if it exists.  And since I have 'COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT=1' enabled the command tries to ask me if I want to install it but the pipe captures the output and hangs.

So the bug may be that COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT doesn't check if its being used in a pipe.  Or that COMPREPLY doesn't check if the command is installed first.

Posted bug with command-not-found group. https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+bug/1534175